# Pandas and csv import into dataframe. How to best to combine date anbd date fields into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that I am trying to import into pandas.

There are two columns of intrest.  date and hour and are the first two cols.

```
E.g.

date,hour,...
10-1-2013,0,
10-1-2013,0,
10-1-2013,0,
10-1-2013,1,
10-1-2013,1,
```

How do I import using pandas so that that hour and date is combined or is that best done after the initial import?

df = DataFrame.from_csv('bingads.csv', sep=',')

If I do the initial import how do I combine the two as a date and then delete the hour?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your own `date_parser`:

```
In [291]: from dateutil.parser import parse
In [292]: import datetime as dt
In [293]: def date_parser(x):
   .....:     date, hour = x.split(' ')
   .....:     return parse(date) + dt.timedelta(0, 3600*int(hour))

In [298]: pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=[[0,1]], date_parser=date_parser)
Out[298]: 
            date_hour  a  b  c
0 2013-10-01 00:00:00  1  1  1
1 2013-10-01 00:00:00  2  2  2
2 2013-10-01 00:00:00  3  3  3
3 2013-10-01 01:00:00  4  4  4
4 2013-10-01 01:00:00  5  5  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply read_csv instead of read_clipboard to handle your actual data:

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date) + pd.to_timedelta(df.hour, unit='D')/24
>>> del df['hour']
>>> df
                 date  ...
0 2013-10-01 00:00:00  NaN
1 2013-10-01 00:00:00  NaN
2 2013-10-01 00:00:00  NaN
3 2013-10-01 01:00:00  NaN
4 2013-10-01 01:00:00  NaN

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: print pd.__version__=0.10.1

Comment: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date) + pd.to_timedelta(df.hour, unit='D')/24
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_timedelta'

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `parse_dates` argument which pandas.read_csv accepts.
You can do something like:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('some.csv', parse_dates=True)
# in which case pandas will parse all columns where it finds dates
df = pandas.read_csv('some.csv', parse_dates=[i,j,k])
# in which case pandas will parse the i, j and kth columns for dates
```

Comment: That won't work, that will just produce a datetime for the first column, the second column will be read as an int, your second line of code will also fail because you want to combine the columns you want to be a single datetime column, all you've done is provide a list of columns to try to parse, so you need to pass a list of lists `[[i,j,k]]`, still all this is irrelevant as the inbuilt date parser fails so you have to use a custom date_parser like @waitingkuo's answer or @alko's approach

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only using the two columns from the cdv file and combining those into one, I would squeeze into a series of datetime objects like so:

```
import pandas as pd 
from StringIO import StringIO
import datetime as dt

txt='''\
date,hour,A,B
10-1-2013,0,1,6
10-1-2013,0,2,7
10-1-2013,0,3,8
10-1-2013,1,4,9
10-1-2013,1,5,10'''

def date_parser(date, hour):
    dates=[]
    for ed, eh in zip(date, hour):
        month, day, year=list(map(int, ed.split('-')))
        hour=int(eh)
        dates.append(dt.datetime(year, month, day, hour))

    return dates    

p=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), usecols=[0,1], 
              parse_dates=[[0,1]], date_parser=date_parser, squeeze=True)

print p
```

Prints:

```
0   2013-10-01 00:00:00
1   2013-10-01 00:00:00
2   2013-10-01 00:00:00
3   2013-10-01 01:00:00
4   2013-10-01 01:00:00
Name: date_hour, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```